# Is there a better way to remove multiples items and shift index from an ArrayList in Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have a Book Shelf that does not not allow more than 100 books. I want to remove Books located at the particular indexes and update the Books indexes after removing a book.

```
Example:
Book0 -> Index  0
Book1 -> Index 1
Book2 -> Index 2
```

**When I remove Book1, Book2 should have an updated index of 1.**

I am not sure here what to use :

- Would an ArrayList a LinkedList or a simple Array be the best choice ? (I need to remove from **specific indexes**)

This is my code :

```
public class Book {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private int writerId;
    private int index;
    // getters & setters
}

public class BookShelf {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private List<Book> books;
    private int nrOfBooks;
}
```

I build a BookShelf. It has to have less than 100 book

```
class BookShelfBuild {

    public static BookShelf createBookShelf() {

        BookShelf booKShelf = new BookShelf();

        booKShelf.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        booKShelf.setName("Awesome books for kids");
        booKShelf.setBooks(getBooks());
        booKShelf.setNrOfBooks(booKShelf.getBooks().size());


        return booKShelf;
    }

    private static List<Book> getBooks() {

        List<Book> booksList = new ArrayList<>();
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 78; i++) {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.setId(randomGenerator.nextInt(10000));
            book.setIndex(i);
            book.setWriterId(randomGenerator.nextInt(10000));
            book.setTitle("Book no: " + randomGenerator.nextInt(10000));
            booksList.add(book);
        }
        return booksList;
    }
}
```

Finally, I check if the indexes are valid. The only thing I could not do is to update the Book's index attribute.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        BookShelf bookShelf = BookShelfBuild.createBookShelf();

        List<Integer> indexesToRemove = Arrays.asList(1);
        List<Book> books = removeBooks(bookShelf, indexesToRemove);

        System.out.println(books);
    }


    public static List<Book> removeBooks(BookShelf bookShelf, List<Integer> indexes) {


        List<Book> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();

        indexes.stream()
                .filter(index -> isValidIndex(bookShelf.getBooks(), index))
                .forEach(index -> {
                    toBeRemoved.add(bookShelf.getBooks().get(index));
                });

        bookShelf.getBooks().removeAll(toBeRemoved);
        return bookShelf.getBooks();
    }

    public static boolean isValidIndex(List<?> list, int index) {
        return index >= 0 && index < list.size();
    }
```

Comment: Chose the list type based on how the list will be used.  If it is to be used in a permanent random access manner, then an `ArrayList` would be appropriate.  If you will be adding and inserting lots of items, a `LinkedList` might be better.  In the latter case, you still need to traverse the list to determine at what point you want to add or delete an item.  Using a `Deque` would allow the search to start at the beginning or end of the list depending on the relative position of the index in question.

Comment: You might want to consider using some kind of `SortedSet` implementation (like `TreeSet`) because you might want to order the books by the `id` and also have a good time complexity for insertions/deletion and search. Because if you think about it, books should be stored uniquely (and you have an `id` field which means that every book as an unique id) and once you hear the word unique, it means that you should start your solution by using `Set`

Comment: Apart from the code that you've shared. Is the underlying intention, to update the `index` field of the Book objects while others get removed? Or is it just their actual index in the collection they are stored to be updated? Another doubt, why would you not use `nrOfBooks` to check if the indexes are valid or not.

Comment: Hi naman, yes my first objective is to find a better way to stream the list of Books and the list of indexes and do the removal in one pipeline. My second goal is indeed to update the index field..because after removing an item, these index fields needs a shift

Comment: Your current code doesn't really show the second goal you are talking about and should the field `index` correspond to the index of the book in the collection or is it just decremented? Aside: If a lookup depends on `index` of the book, why not create a `Map<Integer, Book>` from the list of books within the bookshelf? I mean why is the index required within the `Book` class even?

Comment: Why does a `Book` know its index in an unrelated `List`? Just remove that index and you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past.  If you use a LinkedList and process the indexes to be removed in reverse numerical order, then the indexes don't change while the list is being processed.

```
indexes.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .forEach(bookShelf.getBooks()::remove));
```

Answer (score 0):

Good evening!  If I understand your goal correctly, I would use an array list with .remove(index).  Plug this example into your IDE and see if it does what you are looking for:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<>();

    //This just puts stuff in the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        books.add("Book " + Integer.toString(i));
    }

    //This is just for display
    Consumer<ArrayList<String>> displayBookShelf = (ArrayList<String> data) -> {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Position " + i + ": " + data.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    };

    displayBookShelf.accept(books);

    //Remove first element
    books.remove(0);

    displayBookShelf.accept(books);

    //Remove the third element
    books.remove(2);

    displayBookShelf.accept(books);
}
```